# Help with finding expected value of probability mass function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The question is as follows:

In a popular tale of wizards and witches, a group of them finds themselves in a room with doors which change position, making it impossible to determine which door is which when the room is entered or reentered. Suppose that there are $4$ doors in the room. One door leads out of the building after $4$ hours of travel. The second and third doors return to the room after $3$ and $5$ hours of travel, respectively. The fourth door leads to a dead end, the end of which is a $1.5$ hour trip from the door.

If the probabilities with which the group selects the four doors are $0.2$, $0.1$, $0.2$, and $0.5$, respectively, what is the expected number of hours before the group exits the building?

This is my working thus far:

Let $X =$ number of hours

$X(4) = 0.2$; $X(3) = 0.1$; $X(5) = 0.2$; $X(1.5) = 0.5$;

Expected value $= 4\cdot0.2 + 3\cdot0.1 + 5\cdot0.2 + (1.5+1.5)\cdot0.5 = 3.6$

I doubled the time of door number $44$ as you reach a dead end and have to walk back.

This answer is apparently incorrect and I have no idea what else to try.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are they going to make a second choice if they return into the room?

Comment: I assume so yes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x$ be the expected value.

We can condition on the first move.

Hence,

$$x=4(0.2)+(3+x)(0.1)+(5+x)(0.2)+(0.5)(3+x)$$

$$x=0.8+0.3+0.1x+1+0.2x+1.5+0.5x$$

$$0.2x=0.8+0.3+1+1.5=3.6$$

$$x=18$$

Comment: Why was your last term (0.5)(3+x) ?

Comment: $3$ is the same as your $1.5+1.5$ there are two ways. once you reach back to the starting point, your timer start again, it is as if you start again and not knowing which door to choose.

Comment: I tried to input your answer of the expected value = 7.2 and it appears to be incorrect...

Comment: i misread the question about room $2$ and $3$ let me edit.

Comment: Shouldn't left side of third equation be $.2x$?

Comment: yes, thank you.

Comment: 18 was he correct answer! Could you please explain your methodology? Why did you add x to three terms?

Comment: those terms are the path where you need to restart the door selection, which is expected to take time $x$.